# How do i replace [] brackets using SED

Tags: shell, replace, sed, ksh, brackets

I have a string that i am want to remove punctuation from.

I started with

```
sed 's/[[:punct:]]/ /g'
```

But i had problems on HP-UX not liking that all the time, and some times i would get a 0 and anything after a `$` in my string would dissappear. So i decided to try to do it manually.

I have the following code which works on all my punctuation that I am interested in, except I cannot seem to add square brackets "[]" to my sed with anything else, otherwise it does not replace anything, and i dont get an error, so I am not sure what to fix.

Anyways this is what i currently have and would like to add `[]` to.

```
sed 's/[-=+|~!@#\$%^&*(){}:;'\'''\"''\`''\.''\/''\\']/ /g'
```

BTW I am using KSH on Solaris, Redhat & HP

Comment: Why are you using sed for this?  To replace a large group of characters with a space, it is better to use `tr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final code I ended up with

```
`echo "$string" | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ /g'`
```

I had to put `=` and `-` at the very end.

Answer (score 28):

You need to place the brackets early in the expression:

```
sed 's/[][=+...-]/ /g'
```

By placing the ']' as the first character immediately after the opening bracket, it is interpreted as a member of the character set rather than a closing bracket.  Placing a '[' anywhere inside the brackets makes it a member of the set.

For this particular character set, you also need to deal with `-` specially, since you are not trying to build a range of characters between `[` and `=`.  So put the `-` at the end of the class.

Comment: Yea..that is what i was originally thinking, but when i did that I always recieved an invalid range end error    echo word1$word2 | sed 's/[]-=+|~!@#\$%^&*(){}:;'\'''\"''\`''\.''\/''\\'[]/ /g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 36: Invalid range end

Comment: The 'invalid range' is because of the `-`.  When `-` appears in the middle, sed is trying to create a range of characters.  Use `\-` instead.

Comment: The `-` must be the in first character position in the character class to represent a dash otherwise it may be interpreted as a character class metacharacter that indicates a range of characters.

Comment: @potong, `-` can also be the last character of the set.

Comment: thanks for the tips...I posted my final result as an answer below...I had to move the `=` as well to the end of the regex for it to work.

Answer (score 5):

You can also specify the characters you want to keep [with inversion]:

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ /g'
```

Comment: Thats something I did not even realize was possible. Seems to work pretty good, except for when there is a "$" in my string...anything after the "$" is removed. I tried `echo word1$word2 | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ /g'` and my output was `word1`

Comment: it is the shell interpreting `$word2` as a variable, try `echo 'word1$word2'` or `echo word1\$word2`

Comment: What I ended up doing eventually was saving my string as a variable...then passing the variable inside double quotes. `echo "$string" | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ /g'`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it manually:

```
sed 's/[][\/$*.^|@#{}~&()_:;%+"='\'',`><?!-]/ /g'
```

This remove the 32 punctuation character, the order of some characters is important:

- `-` should be at the end like this `-]`
- `[]` should be like that `[][other characters]`
- `'` should be escaped like that `'\''`
- not begin with `^` like in `[^`
- not begin with `[.`  `[=`  `[:`   and end with `.]`  `=]`  `:]`
- not end with `$]`

here you can have explication of why all that  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03

Answer (score 1):

If you need to replace the brackets totally along with the content then you need to escape it. For example below, replacing the whole brackets along with colon

```
echo "listen [::]:8080 default_server" sed -i 's|listen \[::\]:8080 default_server|listen       8080|' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be handled using the regex capture technique too (Eg: here below) :

```
echo "narrowPeak_SP1[FLAG]" | sed -e 's/\[\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\]/_\1/g'
> narrowPeak_SP1_FLAG

\[ : literal match to open square bracket, since [] is a valid regex
\] : literal match to square close bracket
\(...\) : capture group
\1 : represents the capture group within the square brackets
```